# Stored Procedure with select into parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, parameters

I searched a lot but couldnot find an answer so asking this question

Currently I have a table

```
create table SAM_TEMP
(
col1 number null,
col2 varchar(100) null
)
```

and i am trying to create a stored procedure when i create parametes using column type like shown below is working

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE SP_IN_PARAM(
    INPARAM1 IN SAM_TEMP.COL2%TYPE,
    OUTPARAM2 OUT sam_temp.col1%type )
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT col1 INTO OUTPARAM2 FROM SAM_TEMP WHERE COL2=INPARAM1;
END SP_IN_PARAM;
```

but when i am creating parameter with datatype directly as shown below it is not working could some one help me understand it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE SP_IN_PARAM(
    INPARAM1 IN number,
    OUTPARAM2 OUT varchar(100) )
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT col1 INTO OUTPARAM2 FROM SAM_TEMP WHERE COL2=INPARAM1;
END SP_IN_PARAM;
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Note that it's always helpful to post the error rather than saying that something is "not working".

Comment: it was my first question :), thank you will keep it in mind next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't supply dimensions on the datatypes, just the type name itself. So, this should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE SP_IN_PARAM(
    INPARAM1 IN number,
    OUTPARAM2 OUT varchar )
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT col1 INTO OUTPARAM2 FROM SAM_TEMP WHERE COL2=INPARAM1;
END SP_IN_PARAM;
```

Also, you should generally not use VARCHAR, use VARCHAR2 instead.

Comment: thank you that worked :),I had blanks in my data and it should not be considered as nulls so using varchar instead of varchar2

Comment: @sam - Currently, there is no functionality difference between `varchar` and `varchar2`.  Theoretically, Oracle reserves the right to change the functionality of `varchar` in the future to match the SQL specification and allow non-NULL empty strings.  But that is not the behavior today.

Comment: thanks,intersting,i went back to modify the column now, eventhough i created a varchar column it is automatically converting to varchar2, may be some setting by our dba not sure

Comment: Ah, thanks for the education on VARCHAR and VARCHAR2 difference, Justin.